# Inflater cannot find layout - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, adapter

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ and I have created a new layout-xml file called my_coupons_row but the project doesn't seem to find it. I'm getting `my_coupons_row cannot be resolved or is not a field` error but it is there.

Here is my adapter code:

```
package com.xxx.xxx.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCouponsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;   

    public MyCouponsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);        
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_coupons_row , null); //The error is HERE

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
       // TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
       // TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
       // ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new  HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
      //  title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
       // artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        //duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));

        return vi;
    }
}
```

I'm sure it is something simple but I cannot figure it out.
Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import android.R;
```

you must import `R` from your package

for instance:

```
import com.xxx.xxx.R;
```

Comment: Super man! Thats got it I can't belive I did not find this on google for so long!